# Install module mac os Catalina Anaconda

Tags: python, module, pip, anaconda, gspread

**Set-up**

I've been so stupid to update to Mac OS Catalina, rendering my installation of Anaconda useless. On top of that; I don't have a back-up, so I can't simply downgrade back to Mojave without losing all my stuff.

That said, I've reinstalled Anaconda following reinstallation method 1 of [Anaconda's blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/) on the Catalina issue. Lo-and-behold, Anaconda and Spyder 3.3.6 are working again, allowing me to work with Python 3.7.

Sadly, all my modules seem to be gone, e.g. `import gspread` gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'`.

---

**Tries**

I've reinstalled `gspread` using `pip3`, e.g. `pip3 install gspread`. This gives,

```
Requirement already satisfied: gspread in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.2.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gspread) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.2.1->gspread) (1.25.6)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.2.1->gspread) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.2.1->gspread) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.2.1->gspread) (2019.9.11)
```

but I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'`.

I'm using `gspread` as an example, but so far all installed modules have given the same error.

---

**Issue(s)**

As you can see above, `gspread` is installed in version `Python.framework/Versions/3.6`, but Spyder is running Python `3.7`. I'm not sure but I can imagine this could be the issue. I don't know though how to either install `gspread` for version `3.7` or how to get Spyder to run python `3.6`.

And of course, if this is actually not the issue, I'm not sure what else is up.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note how the `requirement already satisfied` messages all point to

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

which does not look like it would be your `anaconda` installation. So your `pip3` is actually not pointing to your `anaconda` installed python 3.7 version. Your spyder however seems to be configured to use the anaconda distribution.

It might be easily fixed if you activate your base environment using

```
conda activate
```

this should modify the environent variables so that `python` and `pip` calls will go to the anaconda version.

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. Note for Catalina users; as terminal is now zsh shell, I did `source ~/.bash_profile` and then `conda activate`.

Comment: do `conda init zsh` to set up your zsh for anaconda